# Reading simple array JS, only returns first item

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to read all values of an array in JS, but I need your help.

my arrray "item" is as follow:

```
console.log(item);
```

[image: result:]

but when I do :

```
console.log(item.length)
```

result is 1.
I was expected a 8 as result

following code:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
  console.log( item[i]);
}
```

is only returning the first item :

[image]

I am missing something here but don't know what

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve]

Comment: The array is being populated asynchronously.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thats the thing, the script did not behave the same way as the console log. my array wasn't full when I expect to log the content. Thanks